# Can an addition be attached to a post and pillar foundation

Tags: foundation

I am looking to buy a home that has a post and pillar foundation. It is a one bedroom, so one of the requirements for the future is that it be able to be expanded to at least 2 bedroom. It is in the Seattle Greenlake area. My question is whether or not it is possible to build on an addition (one or two story) to the house and connect it to the existing post and pillar foundation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - drill more holes, set more posts, expand away.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and direct response. Would this type of expansion be more difficult or costly than your typical expansion?

Comment: Normally post type foundations are LESS costly than a "standard" foundation. You may need to find the right builder (some will be idiots about working with a post-type structure - find the ones that are not, don't try to work with one that's going to make life difficult because they are not used to it.)